# Create a cell with values from multiple cells

Tags: matlab, cell

I have P being a 1x23 cell. In each cell of P, there is a bunch of numbers in nx1 dimension. Cells in P do not have the same row n (e.g., P{1,1} could be 16x1 and P{1,2} could be 17x1. Now, I'd like to put all the values from all the cells in P (P{1,1}, P{1,2}...P{1,23}) into cell D with the dimension of mx1. m never exceeds 1080 so I can do D=cell(1080,1) then eliminate empty cells later. Right now I am having trouble inputting all the values of P into D. Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>> P = {[1 2].', [3 4 5].'}
>> D = vertcat(P{:})
D =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

If you really need `D` in cell form:

```
>>  D = mat2cell(D,ones(1,size(D,1)),1)
D = 
    [1]
    [2]
    [3]
    [4]
    [5]
```

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted. Thank you, Luis!